# Material Table: TablePagination not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I have issue changing table pages it shows error with or without clicking changing page button error looks like this [image]

downgrading material-ui/core doesnt helped me
this is my version of libraries

```html
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "material-table": "^1.69.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
```

Comment: That's a warning, not an error. To get rid of it, just do as it says: use `onPageChange` instead of `onChangePage`

Comment: The warning is quite clear.

Comment: yes but it doesnt change pages so that warrning is problem and im not using anything its coming from material-ui library

Answer (score 1):

The version of @material/core@4.12.2 is causing that, Due to deprecated methods in TablePagination. As material-table uses this and not upgraded these deprecated methods it is throwing the error. (was happening in 4.12.1 also !)

Downgrade @material-ui/core version to 4.11.4 and keeping the material-table version to 1.69.3.